# Method changes object

Tags: java

Can you explain me such behavior of this code:

```
class Test{
    public List<String> change(List<String> s){
        List<String> tmp = s;
        tmp.add("test");
        return tmp;
    }

    public Integer change(Integer s){
        Integer tmp = s;
        tmp++;
        return tmp;
    }
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        Integer i = new Integer(10);

        Test t = new Test();

        System.out.println(l);
        t.change(l);
        System.out.println(l);

        System.out.println(i);
        t.change(i);
        System.out.println(i);

    }
}
```

And the result is:

```
[]
[test]
10
10
```

Why my list is changed even if inside change() method I create tmp variable and ascribe to it passed argument and my Integer is not change in the same situation?

Comment: Because `tmp++` creates a new `Integer` instance instead of changing the original one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 3):

The trick is here:

```
    Integer tmp = s;
    tmp++;
```

This is roughly equivalent* to:

```
    Integer tmp = s;
    int tmp_unboxed = tmp.intValue;
    tmp_unboxed++;
    tmp = new Integer( tmp_unboxed );
```

The `Integer` is [unboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) to an `int`, then the `int` is incremented and finally the result is [boxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) into a different `Integer` object.

As you can see, the original integer hasn't been modified, a new one was created instead. Whereas in the list example you modify the original list.

*I oversimplified the situation massively to get the point across easier: in particular you don't always get a brand new `Integer` instance, but you always get a **different** `Integer` instance than what you started with..

Answer (score 1):

It is because Integer (same as String, Double etc.) is immutable. It means you cant change the value of that object.

So what happens here?

```
Integer tmp = s;
        tmp++;
```

At this line `Integer tmp = s;`, the instance of Integer (we can call it X) is in memory and reference to it is stored in variable `s`. You copy this reference of X into variable `tmp`.

In this line `tmp++;`, because Integer is immutable, the new instance Y is created in memory, it is given value of instance X and then it is incremented and reference to it is then stored in variable `tmp`.

Variable X is still in memory with unchanged value.

Answer (score 1):

Integer object is immutable. Capture the result from

```
int returnedObject = t.change(i);
```

and print `returnedObject` , you will see modified object

On the other hand list object is mutable. Thats why change is reflected in same object itself

Answer (score 1):

This is due to two features of java: autoboxing and pass-by-reference.

Pass-by-reference means that if an Object is used as parameter of a method, it's location in the memory is passed to the method. Thus the `List`, which is passed as parameter gets modified.

The `Integer` is passed by reference aswell, but here autoboxing applies. `Integer` itself is an `Object` and doesn't support operators; `Integer` is immutable! Autoboxing transforms an `Integer`, or the object representation of a primitive type to the primitive type. Thus the `Integer` is transformed into an `int` and the `int` is modified. This action doesn't affect the `Integer`-object though. What basically happens with the `Integer` in `change` can be roughly described this way:

```
public Integer change(Integer s){
    //store reference to `s` in tmp
    Integer tmp = s;

    //unbox tmp and increment
    tmp++;

    //return tmp
    return tmp;
}

Unboxing:
int unboxed = tmp.intValue();
unboxed++;
tmp = new Integer(unboxed);
```

Comment: Please, please, pretty please. Java is strictly **pass-by-value**. Always. You may get **pass-reference-by-value** but never **pass-by-reference**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: @biziclop you're right. Though that's basically hairsplitting in this context. I've quite often seen (actually most of the time) "pass-by-reference" instead of "pass-reference-by-value".

Comment: In this context it indeed can be seen as hairsplitting but it's an important distinction in general. Things can get really confusing really quickly if we don't use the correct terminology, particularly from someone coming from a language like C++, which **does* support pass-by-reference.